# What is the difference between ReactiveUI's BindTo and ToProperty methods?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

ToProperty() appears to be used for read-only properties that are based on observables but when would I want to use BindTo()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ToProperty is for ViewModels, whereas BindTo is a bit more flexible and is intended to be used in the View layer of your applications. For example (this specific use-case isn't actually a best practice, but it's a good example):

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.ViewModel.IsTextEnabled)
    .Select(x => x ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed)
    .BindTo(this, x => x.TextBox.Visibility);
```

Comment: How would it know the type of 'ViewModel'  ?

Comment: It just knows, deep down in its heart, when the time is right to ViewModel

Comment: Ok, I guess I found it myself. Your code sample in your answer implies that there should be a property called ViewModel in the View. Not sure how BindTo will be seen by MVVM fanatics

Comment: @fahadash you can write the same thing in Xaml with a Converter, but I think it's a nit at best. Perhaps the power is when you move the code to non XAML platforms.